# Why does the result of DataTable.Load with just 1 row behave as if it is a DataRow instead of a DataTable?

Tags: powershell, datatable

I want to query two databases on different servers for the same kind of information, and merge the results into a single list.

I created this example, which works, but only if the first server returns at least *two* rows.

The example uses a list of integers (1 .. 5), but my original code joining two lists of strings has the same problem.

```
# 'quick and dirty' sample
# to be considered insecure,
# do not use as a basis for production code.
function GetData($dbserver, $start, $end)
{
    $qry = "WITH q AS (SELECT  $start AS num UNION ALL SELECT num + 1 FROM q WHERE num < $end) SELECT * FROM q"
    $con = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $con.ConnectionString = "server=$dbserver;database=A2SDataCentral;Integrated Security=SSPI"
    $con.Open()
    $com = $con.CreateCommand()
    $com.CommandText = $qry
    $res = $com.ExecuteReader()
    $table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $table.Load($res)
    return $table
}

$all = $null # erase any result remaining from a previous run
$t1 = GetData "(local)" 1 2
$t2 = GetData "(local)" 3 5
$all = $t1 + $t2
$all
```

The SQL query I use here is just a dummy that generates sequential numbers. It will work only on SQL server.
In this example I run it at the same server (localhost) twice, in reality it has to query two different servers to get two lists of names and join them.

Used as above, this example does what I was trying to make it do, the end result is a list of integers from 1 through 5.

```
num
---
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
```

But when I change the `GetData` calls into this, making the first call return only a single row,

```
$t1 = GetData "(local)" 1 1
$t2 = GetData "(local)" 2 5
```

it crashes with

> Method invocation failed because [System.Data.DataRow] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

So it looks like the `GetData` function returns not a `DataTable`, but a `DataRow` if there is only one row in the result.

I tried this, but that's not the solution either:

```
$all = $t1
$all.Rows.Add($t2)
```

This throws either "Collection was of a fixed size" (`$t1` has 2 rows) or "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" (`$t1` contains 1 row).

Can someone shine a light on why a result with only 1 row causes a different behavior from multiple rows?

(Edit: draw attention to example/insecure nature of script)

Comment: `return $table` -> `Write-Output $table -NoEnumerate`

Comment: @Matthias: that solves it indeed, but why? I had already dumped the result to console after the calls, and that remains exactly the same: one DataRow for the first call, and 4 DataRows for the second. Why an array of DataRows, instead of a DataTable?.

Comment: I've added a proper answer (also, please sanitize your SQL query!)

Comment: Did you found any other way to circunvent this without using "Write-Output" ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You're a victim of PowerShell trying to be a little too friendly

When PowerShell [sees a `DataTable`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/f95dae55f797ea697b88d7412e763c4fb17dea98/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/LanguagePrimitives.cs#L522) being passed from a function on the pipeline it attempts to unravel it and send the [individual rows](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/f95dae55f797ea697b88d7412e763c4fb17dea98/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/LanguagePrimitives.cs#L483-L486) down-stream one by one.

This can be extremely useful when filtering a data set from a db query for example, but obviously extremely frustrating if you're relying on some intrinsic `DataTable` behavior.

To avoid having PowerShell unravel the rows, use `Write-Output $table -NoEnumerator` or - if you add a `CmdletBinding` attribute to your function - you can call `$PSCmdlet.WriteObject($table,$false)` directly:

```
function GetData($dbserver, $start, $end)
{
    $qry = "WITH q AS (SELECT  $start AS num UNION ALL SELECT num + 1 FROM q WHERE num < $end) SELECT * FROM q"
    $con = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $con.ConnectionString = "server=$dbserver;database=A2SDataCentral;Integrated Security=SSPI"
    $con.Open()
    $com = $con.CreateCommand()
    $com.CommandText = $qry
    $res = $com.ExecuteReader()
    $table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $table.Load($res)

    Write-Output $table -NoEnumerate
}
```

or

```
function GetData
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param($dbserver, $start, $end)

    $qry = "WITH q AS (SELECT  $start AS num UNION ALL SELECT num + 1 FROM q WHERE num < $end) SELECT * FROM q"
    $con = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $con.ConnectionString = "server=$dbserver;database=A2SDataCentral;Integrated Security=SSPI"
    $con.Open()
    $com = $con.CreateCommand()
    $com.CommandText = $qry
    $res = $com.ExecuteReader()
    $table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $table.Load($res)

    $PSCmdlet.WriteObject($table,$false)
}
```

### Bonus security review!

I cannot in good conscience answer this question without pointing out that your function is currently susceptible to the most basic form of SQL injection.

What if a user was to pass a non-numeric value as the `$start` or `$end` parameter argument value? Someone could do:

```
$untrustedUserInput = '0 OR 1 = 1; xp_cmdshell "cmd /c calc.exe" --'
```

Congratulations, I now own your database server :)

In this specific instance you can easily mitigate the risk by strongly typing your parameters:

```
function GetData([string]$dbServer, [int]$start, [int]$end)
{
...
```

or

```
param([string]$dbServer, [int]$start, [int]$end)
```

The better solution is to **parameterize** your SQL query:

```
$qry = "WITH q AS (SELECT @start AS num UNION ALL SELECT num + 1 FROM q WHERE num < @end) SELECT * FROM q"
# ...
$com.Parameters.Add('@start','Int').Value = $start
$com.Parameters.Add('@end','Int').Value = $end
```

This way no evil string values will sneak into the query without being sanitized

Comment: Thanks, that answers it. About sanitizing the SQL query, on the one hand you're right, but on the other hand, this is Powershell, not website design or so. This is a local function in an admin script on a management machine. Nobody has access to the function to do that sql injection, who can't launch osql.exe or sqlcmd.exe to get twice the database access in half the time and with one tenth the effort. AND, the sql in the sample code was labeled "just a dummy", it was meant as a quick and (very) dirty way to generate some data rows, and nothing more than that.

Comment: Thanks for this! I've been banging my head against the wall trying to understand what was happening